# Remember data and test tables created in debug mode in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have noticed that my colleague, who uses PyCharm, can access temporary tables created in debug mode, after exiting the debug mode. Is there a way to do this in VS Code?

Comment: I need it for Python